# NET 6 Iterate X509 certificates from pfx file and identify Root CA certificate

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, x509certificate2, ca, pfx

I have an .NET 6 application needing to identify and extract the different certificates from a "child" (client) pfx file. The pfx file contains the root ca certificate and also the child (client) certificate. The certificates from the pfx file are iterated using the X509Certificate2Collection object:

```
var clientCertPfxFilePath = "xxx.pfx";
var certPw = "...";
X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
certCollection.Import(clientCertPfxFilePath, certPw, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in certCollection)
{
   // Check if "cert" is root ca certificate - how?
}
```

Alternatively the certificates can be iterated using the X509Chain object

```
var clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(clientCertPfxFilePath, certPw);
X509Chain certChain = new X509Chain();
certChain.Build(clientCertificate);
foreach (var element in certChain.ChainElements)
{
   // Check if "element" is root ca certificate - how?
}
```

I am looking for a solution how to programmatically identify which from the iterated certificates is the root ca certificate, with either one of the both above code snippets

Answer (score 1):

For `X509Chain` the answer is easy...  if chain.Build returned `true` then the chain ends in a trusted element, and therefore the last element will be a trusted root certificate.  (If you are reading this in the far future then maybe X509Chain will have been enhanced to trust non-root anchors, but that would almost certainly require a different call pattern than was presented here.)

For certificates, detecting a self-*signed* certificate is hard, but you can check if a certificate is self-*issued* fairly easily:

```
bool selfIssued = cert.SubjectName.RawData.SequenceEquals(cert.IssuerName.RawData);
```

(That is, a self-issued certificate is one whose subject name and issuer name are encoded identically.)

A self-signed certificate is a self-issued certificate whose public key can validate the signature on the certificate.  The signature verification isn't exposed through .NET, so it's hard to check, but many applications assume that self-issued and self-signed are the same anyways, so you can, too.

Comment: Thanks, it helped! The certificates are indeed self-signed. I needed the root ca certificate for the ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback in HttpClientHandler where I used the sample code from https://www.meziantou.net/custom-certificate-validation-in-dotnet.htm#dotnet-5-way-of-vali , as I did not want to install the child pfx file containing the cert.hierarchy in the certificate store. Is it possible to see from the certificate chain that the child cert.is signed by the root ca certificate?

Comment: If the root certificate is not installed in the windows certificate store, chain.Bild returns false... The idea was to get the root ca certificate without any entries in the certificate store, just using the client pfx file...

Comment: The last certificate in the chain is indeed the root ca certificate, even if chain.Build returns false. Is there any other way for some extra check that the last certificate is really the root ca certificate ?

Comment: Would this code to get the self-signed root ca certificate be reliable enough?   X509ChainElement chainElement = chain.ChainElements[chain.ChainElements.Count - 1];
foreach (X509ChainStatus status in chainElement.ChainElementStatus)
{
    if (status.Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.PartialChain)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else if (status.Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot)
   {
       // found root ca certificate!
       rootCaCert = chainElement.Certificate;
       break;
   }
}

Comment: @RickyTad The code you linked to looks to be correct, and will only verify chains issued by roots specified in CustomTrustStore.  The only thing in .NET that does a "is signed by" is X509Chain during its path walk.  And, yes, unless the chain says PartialChain the final element is a self-signed cert.

Answer (score 0):

@bartonjs Unfortunately the solution with chain.Build does not work on a computer where no certificates were installed in the windows certificate store. The root ca certificate is available in the certificate chain after calling "chain.Build" only on the computers where the root ca is installed in the certificate store. On these computers the certificate chain has 2 elements, the client certificate and the root ca certificate. On the computers having no root ca installed in the certificate store the chain contains only 1 element after the "chain.Build" call (the client certificate). The root ca does not appear anymore, although using absolutely the same pfx file!